# Running spec after promise has been resolved

Tags: jasmine, protractor

I came across an issue with running a spec that should be executed after a promise has been resolved. See the commented simplified example below.

I tried using IIFE or calling `done()` function in the spec but none of these seemed to work.

```
// getIds() is a simple promise which returns an array of ids
getIds().then(function (ids) {
    console.log('IDS: ' + ids); // all good so far

    // This test is never run
    it('dummy test', function () { 
        console.log('TEST HAS BEEN RUN');
    });
});
```

Comment: Have you tried putting an assertion (expect) in your test? I'm not sure that a test will run without an assertion.

Comment: No, this doesn't have any effect on the issue.

Comment: are you getting any error message? If so please post it.

Comment: No, the test is run successfully, but reports that 0 out of 0 specs were executed.

Comment: Why do you want put the entire `it` spec inside the callback, but not just an expectation?

Comment: I want to loop over the result of the promise and dynamically generate `it` blocks. The above example doesn't demonstrate that but I wanted to keep it simple. The example shows the actual problem, generating the `it` blocks is the easy part.

Comment: Take a look at these issues: [Dynamically created tests based on Async result](https://github.com/jasmine/jasmine/issues/412) and [Support adding describe() and it() calls at runtime](https://github.com/jasmine/jasmine/issues/559), generation of suites and specs for async code seems to be not possible for current Jasmine version.

Comment: Good links, thanks. It seems like I'll have to turn the `getIds()` into a method with blocking wait.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `browser.wait()` to wait until your promise is complete. Or you can put your test inside the then block:

```
it('should test', function() {
  getIds().then(function (ids) {
    // some action.
    expect()...
  });
});
```

Also, you can put the promise in a beforeEach or a beforeAll (jasmine 2). Assign the ids to a variable declared inside a describe. The value should be available for your test to use.