# Async call in beforeAll

Tags: jasmine, protractor

Here are 2 samples of the same test. The only difference is that first one uses a promise in `beforeAll` block to assign a value to the variable while the second one assigns the value directly.

I raised a similar question [Running spec after promise has been resolved](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32480430/running-spec-after-promise-has-been-resolved) with one of the comments pointing to this issue https://github.com/jasmine/jasmine/issues/412 which says that this is not supported in Jasmine. Has somebody figured out any workaround?

**This fails with** `TypeError: Cannot read property 'forEach' of undefined`

```
describe('Async car test', function () {

    var cars;

    beforeAll(function (done) {
        // getCars() is a promise which resolves to ['audi', 'bmw']
        getCars().then(function (data) {
            cars = data;
            console.log(cars) // ['audi', 'bmw']
            done();
        });
    });

    cars.forEach(function (car) {
        it('car ' + car, function () {
            expect(car).toBe(car);
        });
    });
});
```

**This works fine**

```
describe('Car test', function () {

    var cars = ['audi', 'bmw'];

    cars.forEach(function (car) {
        it('car ' + car, function () {
            expect(car).toBe(car);
        });
    });
});
```

Comment: In my mind it should work, as `done()` should be called before `cars.forEach()`, but it apparently doesn't. What about making different blocking wait in beforeAll, so you basically shift to "This works fine" case? http://docsplendid.com/tags/wait-for-element . 
Or, second idea as cars should be promise as well, what about: `cars.then(function (cars) { cars.forEach(function(car{... `

Comment: I tried both of your suggestions, introducing blocking wait in `getCars()` and also leaving out `beforeAll` completely and generating test cases directly with `getCars().then(function (cars) { cars.forEach(function(car) {...` but none of these work. In my original example, it seems to me the problem is that jasmine will run `cars.forEach` before the `done()` callback in `beforeAll` is executed. And I haven't figured out any way around it.

Comment: Can you try to nest the `.forEach()` inside another `it` block and see if it works? That might solve the issue of forEach loop running before a test spec - `it('check cars: ', function () { cars.forEach(function (car) {
        it('car ' + car, function () {
            expect(car).toBe(car);
        });
    }); });`

Comment: Wrapping it in another `it` block will actually execute the spec but it will report only the top level ìt` block as pass or fail. It won't report the dynamically generated `it` blocks from the `cars.forEach...` loop. So if 1 of the assertions in the `cars.forEach` loop fails, the whole `it` block is reported as failed. And that's what I'm trying to avoid. I want to have 1 ìt` block per car. I also tried wrapping it inside the `describe` block instead of `it` block but that doesn't work either. Content inside the nested `describe` block is executed before the promise in `beforeAll` has resolved

Answer (score 2):

Posting it as an answer, because I can't see things properly in comments.

I'm actually generating tests in my spec as well, and I'm using https://www.npmjs.com/package/jasmine-data-provider , I think you probably cannot generate it directly from resolved promise. And wrapping in another it doesn't work for you. This should work:

```js
var using = require('jasmine-data-provider');
using(cars.forEach, function (car) {
  it(car + ' should be' + car, function () {
    expect(car).toBe(car);
  });
});
```

Comment: I tried using jasmine-data-provider with no luck, it still gives the `TypeError: Cannot read property 'forEach' of undefined`. I'm starting to accept that this is a serious limitation of Jasmine and there is no way around how Jasmine executes specs. Thanks for all your suggestions in this thread, I really appreciate it.

Answer (score 2):

This is not an issue with jasmine, it is an issue with your code.
beforeAll does not block subsequent code below the statement. it blocks code that is defined in it('should ...', (done)=>{...});

```js
it('should have cars', (done) => {  
    cars.forEach(function (car) {
        expect(car).toBe(car);
    });
});
```

Comment: This will only run the `forEach` loop inside the test case. The original question is about running it outside of the `it` block to dynamically generate test cases.

Answer (score 0):

Since Jasmine does not support adding tests at runtime, the trick is to request the asynchronous data before starting Jasmine, and then using the retrieved data during runtime instead. This can be achieved with a singleton and [programmatically](https://jasmine.github.io/2.1/node.html#section-21) starting Jasmine.

[See here for a working example.](https://github.com/pizzaisdavid/jasmine-async-each)

```
// car-collection.js
class CarCollection {

  static load() {
    return this.request()
      then((data) => this.cars = data);
  }

  static request() {
    // in practice this function would do something cooler
    return Promise.resolve(['audi', 'bmw']); 
  }
}

modules.export = CarCollection;
```

Since `CarCollection` has methods that are `static` they will be shared across imports and `this.cars` will persist.

```
// launcher.js
const Jasmine = require('jasmine');
const CarCollection = require('./car-collection');

CarCollection.load()
  .then(() => {
    console.log(`car count is ${CarCollection.cars.length}`); // prints: car count is 2
    const jasmine = new Jasmine();
    jasmine.loadConfigFile(...); // path to jasmine.json
    jasmine.execute();
  });
```

An important step here is configure jasmine to know where to look for the test files. Either by [loading a config](https://jasmine.github.io/2.1/node.html#section-Load_configuration_from_a_file_or_from_an_object.) or [passing specifics](https://jasmine.github.io/2.1/node.html#section-22) into the `execute` function.

```
// car.spec.js
const CarCollection = require('./car-collection');

describe('test', function () {

  CarCollection.cars.forEach((car) => {

    it('test' + car, () => {
      expect(car).toBe(car);
    });
  });
});
```

Now run `node ./launcher.js` and the tests should run.